# Magento session not loaded on every page

Tags: php, magento, session

I have a weird problem with a Magento store I am developing for a client. It appears to be session related. The session gets initiated at some pages but not others.

Two examples:

1. If I am logged in as a customer on the frontend, Magento shows the "logged in" menu on top, but only on /checkout and /customer URLs. On all other URLs, Magento reverts to the "logged out" menu.
2. If I place items in my basket, the basket count stays 0 except for when I visit /checkout and /customer URLs, then it shows the correct count.

So it seems Magento is using a different session for /customer and /checkout URLs than it is for all catalog and other module urls.

Can anybody point me in the right direction to restore the default behaviour? With Magento remembering the session on ALL pages? I have searched google and SO but have not found any issue even remotely similar.

Please, also note that I:

- Tried to revert the website to the default and base templates, but still the issue remains
- Emptied the cache in every possible way but still nothing changed
- Have built quite a few Magento stores and have never run into a similar issue

Session storage is in DB, but setting that to file storage does not change anything.

For your reference: the website address is http://creastone.eleven59.nl

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure there's no some full page cache or something like this installed? or proxy level cache such as nginx?

Comment: I don't have full page cache. The server is Apache running on cPanel. I have APC enabled.. could that be a problem?

Comment: Update: I disabled APC for the domain but still no luck.. Problem stays the same. I have also disabled all Magento cache. Memcached is also active, but not enabled in Magento config (local.xml). But if I empty memcached via telnet flush_all, the problem stays the same.

Comment: Update2: I have two other Magento stores running on the same server (but on different domains) and those have no issues, even though those are cache-enabled and they use both Memcached and APC.

Comment: Are you certain the session isn't fine and the template code is broke for showing the cart?

Comment: As I said in the initial post, I also have the same behavior if I revert back to the default skin and clear the cache. So template code can't be the issue, right? Also, the mini cart is not the only thing missing data; the customer menu is also shown as "logged out" even though I am logged in. On the /checkout and /customer URLs, everything is fine, on all other URLs, nothing is fine.

Comment: Because you revert to default skin/template but problem still remain, so I think this problem come from third-party modules. You should check by de-active them one by one.

Comment: Weird.. I would agree with you, but I have de-activated them all one by one and nothing helped..